# ScintillaNet autocomplete weird behaviour with character '-'

Tags: autocomplete, scintilla

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete system for my code editor using ScintillaNet. Everything seems to works fine, but I realized that if the populated list contains strings with characters '_' i.e, the format X_XYZ, the focus is loosed and no string is selected (works for X, X_ and X_X but looses the focus for the following letters).

What I'm trying to do is to show the list after the text "this.".

Strings with this issue are for example:

```
p_M_Restart -> OK
p_MDWTest -> Fails at D and following letters
```

My code in the CharAdded event looks like this:

```
if (editor.GetWordFromPosition(editor.CurrentPos - 1) == TXT_THIS
    && e.Ch == '.')
{
    editor.AutoComplete.List = Parameters.ToList();
    editor.AutoComplete.SingleLineAccept = false;
    editor.AutoComplete.FillUpCharacters = "([";
    editor.AutoComplete.Show();      
}
```

Is '_' a spcecial case? or is any consideration needed with this character?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved following the ScintillaNet issue:

https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/workitem/34165

Hope this will help other people.